# chartjs - how to set the order in which the different charts are displayed

Tags: angular, charts, chart.js

[image]

There are 3 different datasets in here. I want to display them one over the other without being able to see the lines.

```
datasets: [
   {
    data : someData
    borderColor: "#0070C0"
    borderWidth: 3
    barThickness: "flex"
    fill: "origin"
    backgroundColor: "#0070C0"
    order: 4
   }
]
```

I tried setting the order for the datasets as shown above. I still get the chart I am showing in the image.

Comment: Can you put your jsfiddle code?

Comment: Do you want to hide only the lines or the points as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hide the lines with a line like `borderColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0)"`

You can't simply hide only the points behind other areas, you can hide all or none.

Here's my JSBin where I tested it: https://jsbin.com/vuyigocexi/2/edit?js,output

Btw if you omit the `order`-property, the order of the datasets in your code are used.

If you provide more information I could maybe help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Define your dataset list like below:

```
var data = {
  labels: ["May 1", "May 2", "May 3", "May 4", "May 5", "May 6", 
                 "May 7", "May 8", "May 9", "May 10", "May 11", "May 12"],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Red",
      fill: true,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(196, 93, 105, 1)",
      data: dataPack2,
    },
    {
      label: "Blue", 
      fill: true, 
      backgroundColor: "rgba(32, 162, 219, 1)",
      data: dataPack1,
    },
  ]
};
```

You can change data orders with reordering data objects in dataset list.

```
var myLineChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), {
  type: 'line',
  data: data
});
```

Comment: And how does that hide the lines and the points behind them? https://jsbin.com/tajureruwa/1/edit?js,output